# When averaging rasters, is there a way to calculate the n number of non-NaN values per pixel used to calculate the pixel means?

Tags: python, r, raster, arcgis, qgis

I have about 40 rasters (tiffs). I averaged the rasters, which is straightforward. As a second output however I would like to determine the *n* number of non-NaN values per pixel used to calculate each pixel mean, and display this as a raster. Basically, I need to know for each pixel how many values were used to calculate the mean. Is this possible? I am looking for solutions either with GIS (either ArcGIS or QGIS is fine), Python or R. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do that with R using the `terra` package

```
library(terra)
s <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))   

m <- mean(s)
n <- sum(!is.na(s))
```

Or the `raster` package

```
library(raster)
b <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
mb <- mean(b)
nb <- sum(!is.na(b))
```

Comment: Sorry just amending my comment to say I used the raster package instructions and it worked.